# Euler-Lagrange equation, derivative calculation

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, chain-rule, euler-lagrange-equation

Let we have $F(u)=\int_A\mathcal{L}(x,u,u')dx$, where $dx$ is Lebesgue measure, $A$ is open and bounded with regular boundary, $\mathcal{L}\in\mathcal{C}^2(A\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n)$ and convex $\forall x\in A$, also $u(x)\in\mathcal{C}^1(\bar A)$. Moreover we introduce $f(t)=F[\psi]=F[u+t(v-u)]$, where $v(x)\in\mathcal{C}^1(\bar A), \ t\in [0,1]$ and I want to calculate $\frac{df}{dt}$, but I am a bit confused and not sure.
My attempt:

$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\int_A\mathcal{L}[x,u+t(v-u),(u+t(v-u))']dx$

Since $\mathcal{L}$ is continuous and bounded, we can put the differential under the integral sign.

$\frac{d\mathcal{L}}{dt}=\frac{d\mathcal{L}}{d\psi}\frac{d\psi}{dt}+\frac{d\mathcal{L}}{d\psi'}\frac{d\psi'}{dt}+\frac{d\mathcal{L}}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=\mathcal{L}_\psi\cdot(v-u)+\langle\nabla_{\psi'}\mathcal{L},\nabla v-\nabla u\rangle$

and here I am confused because professor got here

$\mathcal{L}_u\cdot(v-u)+\langle\nabla_{\xi}\mathcal{L},\nabla v-\nabla u\rangle$, where $\xi=u'$.

What I am missing? thank you

Comment: I can't see the diffeerence between what you got and what your prof got. Maybe it's just notation? Like, $u'=\psi'$?

Comment: no, I meant that $\psi=u+t(v-u)$

Comment: so, it looks like your mistake is taking $\mathcal L$ to be a function of $(x,\psi,\psi')$ when your professor is taking it to be a function of $(x,u,\xi)$ and composing it the variation. In other words, $\mathcal L_\psi$ does not even make sense because $\mathcal L$ is not a function of $\psi$...